# Problems typesetting footnotes with RevTeX 4-1

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, revtex, endnotes

The RevTeX classes, for some of the APS journals, typeset all footnotes in the bibliography (as endnotes). Although it works perfectly if I try with RevTeX4,  I consistently have problems doing this under RevTeX4-1. Here's a compact example.

```
\documentclass[prl,aps,10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\title{A nearly minimal example using RevTeX4-1}
\author{Niel de Beaudrap}
\noaffiliation
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
    In this letter, we attempt to typeset a footnote.
    We find that it fails to be properly typeset with the package ``revtex4-1'',
    whereas it works properly with the package ``revtex4''.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

The following should appear in the bibliography~\footnote{%
    This compiles correctly under RevTeX4.}.
It is our hope that others are able to reproduce our results
and identify potential sources of error. 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

If I use the `nofootinbib` option (which turns off end notes), the package behaves properly under both RevTeX4 and RevTeX4-1.

I can manually insert my footnotes into the bibliography, but I would rather not. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to run bibtex in order for the footnotes to appear, so in particular, you can't use `\begin{thebibliography}{99}...\end{thebibliography}` but rather `\bibliography{mybib}`, which RevTeX4.1 will rewrite as though it says `\bibliography{mybib,mypaperNotes}` and create a file `mypaperNotes.bib` with the endnotes in it.

Comment: Actually, this is documented on page 13 of the RevTeX4-1 manual as well. It's a bit disappointing that this is necessary, but as it seems to be the intended workflow of RevTeX4-1 (and does solve the problem), this is clearly the correct answer.